# Apache Ignite RESTful Request Failure

Tags: rest, gridgain, ignite

Can someone please shed some light on this cryptic exception being thrown when I try to connect and send a REST request to a local Ignite node ?

The request looks like this :
http://127.0.0.1:8080/ignite?cmd=top

There is no response from Ignite but I see the following in logs :

[GridTcpRestProtocol] Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Failed to parse incoming packet (invalid packet start) [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [selectorIdx=2, queueSize=0, writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, recovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:8080, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:64501, createTime=1439344656124, closeTime=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd=278, sndSchedTime=1439344656124, lastSndTime=1439344656124, lastRcvTime=1439344656124, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=GridTcpRestParser [jdkMarshaller=JdkMarshaller [], routerClient=false], directMode=false]], accepted=true]], b=47]]

I am not able to figure out whats going wrong here. Searching the web for this issue I did not yeild much success. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shonapapa, could you provide exact version of Ignite and node configuration you used to start node. Also, check that only one version of Ignite is running and no other else connecting to the port.

Comment: Ignite incubating Ver. 1.3.0 and the config XML is :                                   <bean id="DataManager.rest.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ConnectorConfiguration">
  <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
  <property name="port" value="8080"/>
  <property name="jettyPath" value="/config/Rest-Jetty-Config.xml"/>
 </bean> 

 <bean id="DataManager.grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
  <property name="gridName" value="DataManagerGrid"/>
  <property name="connectorConfiguration" ref="DataManager.rest.cfg" />
 </bean>

Comment: The Rest-Jetty-Config.xml is exactly same as sample XML provided by Ignite Wiki at  http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/AI10/Configuration#Configuration-SampleJettyXMLconfiguration

Comment: Can you try running with all defaults? Once you enabled ignite-rest-http module, you can connect through port 8080 - no need to provide ConnectorConfiguration unless you want to make any explicit changes.

Comment: @Valentin : That did the trick. Removed Connector configuration and its working as expected. Thanks a bunch to you all for quick response.